# How to get the data from a Mat angular dialog in other component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, components

SO I have a component: DetailComponent:

```
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit  {


  @Input() participant: ParticipantInfoDTO;

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.participant = route.snapshot.data['participant'];
  }

  ngOnInit() {}




  openEcheqSelectorDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(EcheqSelectorComponent, {
      width: '600px',
      maxHeight: 'calc(100vh - 2em)',
      data: {
        participant: console.log('participantIDTest', this.participant)
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And the data from : this.participant is like this:

```
{participantId: "ac3d1836-2e36-4947-a62f-04cd00425bcc", email: "k@endrix.org", gender: "Male", fullName: "k kaas", firstName: "k", …}
```

So I get the correct data back.

But now I want also receive the same data in other component. The other component looks like this:

```
export class EcheqSelectorComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subscriptions = new Subscription();
  echeqs: EcheqFamilyInfo[] = [];
  allEcheqs: EcheqFamilyInfo[] = [];
  echeqFamily: EcheqFamilyInfo;
  searchInput = '';
  filtering = false;
  participantInfo: ParticipantInfoDTO;
  echeqsToSend: EcheqFamilyInfo[] = [];
  echeqSubmissionBatchDTO: EcheqSubmissionBatchDTO;
  participantIds$: Observable<string[]>;
  patientId: string;

  public participantIds: string[] = [];

  constructor(
    private apiService: EcheqDefinitionService,
    private dialog: MatDialogRef<EcheqSelectorComponent>,
    public selectedParticipantService: SelectedParticipantsService,
    private submissionService: EcheqSubmissionMedicalService,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data: any
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptions.add(
      this.apiService.listEcheqFamilies().subscribe(families => {
        this.echeqs = families;
        this.allEcheqs = families;
      })
    );

    this.subscriptions.add(
      this.selectedParticipantService.getParticipantIds
        .pipe(tap(participantIds => console.log('Participants', participantIds)))
        .subscribe()
    );

      console.log('participantId',   this.participantInfo.participantId);
  }
}
```

But if I do this:

```
  console.log('participantId',   this.participantInfo.participantId);
```

Then I will receive this error:

```
EcheqSelectorComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'participantId' of undefined
    at EcheqSelectorComponent.push../src/app/participant/modules/echeq/components/echeq-selector/echeq-selector.component.ts.EcheqSelectorComponent.ngOnInit (echeq-selector.component.ts:62)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:18620)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:19884)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:19846)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:20480)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:20440)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (EcheqSelectorComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:20432)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:19828)
    at callViewAction (core.js:20069)
```

So what I have to change to receive the correct data?

Thank you

If I do this:

```
 public participantIds: string[] = [];

  constructor(
    private apiService: EcheqDefinitionService,
    private dialog: MatDialogRef<EcheqSelectorComponent>,
    public selectedParticipantService: SelectedParticipantsService,
    private submissionService: EcheqSubmissionMedicalService,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, public dialogRef:MatDialogRef<EcheqSelectorComponent>
  )
  {
    this.participantInfo = data.participant;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptions.add(
      this.apiService.listEcheqFamilies().subscribe(families => {
        this.echeqs = families;
        this.allEcheqs = families;
      })
    );

    this.subscriptions.add(
      this.selectedParticipantService.getParticipantIds
        .pipe(tap(participantIds => console.log(' selected Participants', participantIds)))
        .subscribe()
    );

      console.log('participantId', this.dialogRef.id);
  }
```

But how to get the

```
{participantId: "0bde3c11-50a2-4e4e-a9e3-08d6cccff86a"}
```

So the participantId?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can receive data back from a dialog

```
async deleteRequest(id) {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationComponent, {
  width: '250px',
  data: 'Are you sure you want to delete this request?'
});
 dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(async result => {
  if (result == "yes") {
   console.log('yes');
  }
  else{
   console.llog('No');
  }
});
```

On your dialog

```
export class ConfirmationComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, public dialogRef: 
MatDialogRef<ConfirmationComponent>) { }

onNoClick() {
this.dialogRef.close('no');
}

onYesClick() {
this.dialogRef.close('yes');
}

ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

you can return data as per your requirement and send it to other.

Comment: can't you get id by data.participant.participantId ?

Comment: I try it in the ngOninit(){  console.log(this.data.participant.participantId);}

Comment: EcheqSelectorComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'participantId' of undefined
    at EcheqSelectorComponent.push../src/app/participant/modules/echeq/components/echeq-selector/echeq-selector.component.ts.EcheqSelectorComponent.ngOnInit (echeq-selector.component.ts:65)

Comment: Can you host a demo code on stackblitz? it would be helpful

Comment: I don't know how, because with also the service.